How can a localhost server be embedded inside an Electron app in MacOS sandbox?
I have an Electron app that serves a simple localhost
server. Everything works perfectly in development and in the electron-builder packaged app, but not within the macOS sandbox, which is necessary to be able to publish to the Mac App Store.
I tried adding
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
<true/>

in entitlements.plist but the sandboxed version crashed at server.listen(PORT_NAME).
